# How to use slim.dataset_data_provider when I have multiple TFRecords?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using slim.dataset_data_provider. For example,

```
my_dataset = slim.dataset.Dataset(
           data_sources='datasets/my_data.tfrecord`,
           reader=reader,
           decoder=decoder,
           ...)

provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(
           my_dataset,
           ...)
```

I found this is very conveinent. However, the `my_data.tfrecord` is already now around 15GB, and I am supposed to receive more data. Instead of re-creating a huge TFRecord file, I want to keep several TFRcord files such as `my_data_A.tfrecord`, `my_data_B.tfrecord`, and so on.

If I have multiple TFrecord files, how can I use slim.dataset_data_provider? Or, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an experiment, I think one can use several tfrecords such as

```
my_dataset = slim.dataset.Dataset(
       data_sources=['a.tfrecord`, 'b.tfrecord`],
       reader=reader,
       decoder=decoder,
       ...)
```